# How to get notified between main() and applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:) in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm writing a framework and want my function to be executed after host app starts running main() and before applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:). **willFinishLaunchingNotification** is great but unfortunately it's only available on macOS.

My first try is to hook UIApplicationMain() with [fishhook](https://github.com/facebook/fishhook), but later found this library causes a few crashes on iOS 15 devices.

Comment: See WWDC 2019 [Optimizing App Launch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/423/) for high-level overview of start up process.

Comment: @Rob I don't think it solves my problem.